# How can I change a variable in Jekyll _config.yml dynamically?

Tags: html, configuration-files, jekyll, liquid

Hi I'm working on a Jekyll project and I need to put a variable in _config.yml that I want to change dynamically from the template code.

This is what I want to do, but I can't get it to work. Is it possible to do this?

In _config.yml:

```
my_var: "value"
```

In template.html:

```
{% site.my_var = "newvalue" %}

{% case site.my_var %}
  {% when "value" %}
    //do this
  {% when "newvalue" %}
   //do this instead
{% endcase %}
```

Comment: Can you describe your use case? Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 8):

While you apparently cannot use [Liquid conditionals](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers) nor Environment Variables (as in many other build scripts), you can do a selective overrides with a second yml file:

```
$> bundle exec jekyll serve --drafts --incremental --config _config.yml,_dev.yml
```

with a `_dev.yml`:

```
# overrides title in _config.yml
title: "My Website (dev mode)"

# see my styles uncompressed for dev work
sass:
    style: uncompressed
```

Perhaps that fits your needs...

Comment: Wow I didn't know that.

Comment: Using a second config file has always been my way of building an extra copy with a few small differences. So must +1 this answer.